# Highchart not showing

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts

I used highcharts and I want to show data from database. The problem is the chart is not showing. It's my first time using JSON. Is there something wrong in my query that's why the graph is not showing?

Script

```
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('fetchdata.php',function($wv3) { 
       Highcharts.chart('container', {
                            chart: {
                                     type: 'line'
                                   },
                            title: {
                                     text: 'Daily Voltage'
                                   },
                            xAxis: {
                                    categories: ['12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM','12:00 PM', '1:00 PM', '2:00 PM', '3:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '6:00 PM', '7:00 PM', '8:00 PM', '9:00 PM', '10:00 PM', '11:00 PM']
                                    },
                            yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                       text: 'Voltage A'
                                        }
                                    },
                            plotOptions: {
                                    line: {
                                         dataLabels: {
                                             enabled: true
                                            },
                                         enableMouseTracking: false
                                        }
                                    },
                                    series: [{
                                        name: 'Feeder 1',
                                        data: wv3
                                    }]
                });
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
</div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

fetchdata.php

```
$weekly1 = "SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(CAST(Batal_Feeder_1.time as datetime) , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH') as Time, 
                                Batal_Feeder_1.Ia, Batal_Feeder_1.Ib, Batal_Feeder_1.Ic, Batal_Feeder_1.Kwtotal, Batal_Feeder_1.pftotal,Batal_Feeder_1.Kwhtotal, Va AS VoltageA
                        FROM Batal_Feeder_1 
                        JOIN (
                                SELECT MIN(time) as mints FROM Batal_Feeder_1   
                                WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, time))) = '".$_SESSION['date']."' 
                                GROUP BY CONVERT(date,time), DATEPART(hh, time)
                            )tt 
                        ON Batal_Feeder_1.time = tt.mints 
                        ORDER BY Time ASC";

                        $weekly2 = sqlsrv_query($db, $weekly1);

                        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($weekly2)) {
                            $wv1 = $row['VoltageA'];
                            $wv2 = $row['time'];

                            $wv3[] = [$wv1];

                        }


                    echo json_encode($wv3);
```

Comment: In PHP : You don't use `$wv2` in `$wv3` ? In Javascript you recept `$wv3` but use `data: wv3` in the serie.

Comment: no. when I tried data: $wv3, it still doesn't work @Core972

Comment: Add a console.log of `$wv3` in javascript and check if there is **numbers** Highcharts can read [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data)

Comment: your this line `</div id="container"` is wrong which should be `<div id="container"` instead, use the browser console (F12) & reload the page to see if errors are there,also check the Network tab for the results of getJSON

Comment: @YumiHamano did you check my comment? if the Highchart js has an error you should be able to see it in the console.